# I have downloaded a text file. Instead of downloading I want to display it in a html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I try to convert a pdf as base64 string. I converted it and saving it to text file. Iam able to download the text file. But i dont want to download it instead of download it i want to display it in a html page. While clicking that text file i should be able to view the content of the text file. Is there any possible way to do it in javascript.

Comment: What have you tried so far, please provide minimal working example.!

Comment: Use simple anchor, it will open the text file on html page.  <a href="yourfileurl.txt">Test</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attached the below Link

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-flower-nxmtw?from-embed

You can use a iframe and put the text file link to src

Note* - the above solution is with the limited information i have understood .